# Laravel 5.4- Delete array from session variable

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am storing data in array format using push method.

```
$request->session()->push('orders', [
    $request->product_id => 1
]);
```

The structure of data stored is like this-

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      11 => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      11 => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      9 => int 1
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      8 => int 1
```

How can I delete a particular nested array.

I tried this but not working-

```
 $orders = $request->session()->get('orders');
    foreach ($orders as $order_key => $order) {
        foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $id){
                $value = $request->session()->pull('orders'.$order_key, 'default');
            }
        }
    }
```

Here `$id` is the variable which stores the product_id of the product which I want to remove from session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may as well manage first the `$orders` Array and then afterwards, deal with the Session Data like the Code below suggests:

```
    $orders = $request->session()->get('orders');
    foreach ($orders as $order_key => $order) {
        foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $id){
                // SIMPLY UNSET THE $orders[$order_key] ENTRY
                unset($orders[$order_key]);
            }
        }
    }

    // RE-STORE THE UPDATED SESSION-DATA TO SESSION
    $request->session()->put('orders', $orders);
```